# Laravel Socialite not working on production

Tags: laravel, laravel-socialite

I have code that works fine locally but shows me errors on Heroku.

> exception: "GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException"
>   Client error: `POST https://github.com/login/oauth/access_token` resulted in a `404 Not Found`

Problem is with the line `$accessToken = $driver->getAccessTokenResponse($request->code);` So it must get the access token and then exchange token for a user but for some reason shows me an error. Everything works fine locally this is only in productions.

```
public function redirectToProvider($service, Request $request)
{
    $driver = Socialite::driver($service);

    $accessToken = $driver->getAccessTokenResponse($request->code);

    $data = $driver->getUserByToken($accessToken['access_token']);

    $user = (new User())->exists($data['email']);

    //

    $token = JWTAuth::fromUser($user);

    return response()->json([
        'access_token' => $token,
        'user' => [
            'data' => $user,
            'token' => $token
        ]], 200);
}
```

Does anyone have an idea? Thanks!